# Private moderator message translation issues

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, localization, private-messaging

Private moderator message contains several fields, in particular:

- from
- to
- bcc

> [image]

- "from" is used in a lot of situations, and should be replaced here to "от" instead of "из". I.e. new context (REFERS_TO) should be added to the string to prevent losing translations in other places.
- "bcc" is [not ready for translation at all](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=bcc), it should be made translatable.

Comment: "Bcc" means "blind carbon copy", i.e. a copy is sent to someone without revealing this to the other recipients. The concept should be familiar from email; how are popular email clients localizing this? A rephrasing like "secret copy" might work.

Comment: Perhaps replacing "From" with "Sender" in the English source would simplify this dilemma going forward.

Comment: @tripleee localization engine on SE already supports the conception of CONTEXT (REFERS_TO), so changing the source string is not necessary and may lead to other incorrect situations (in general) with translation since the same source string may be needed to translated differently depending on the usage context.

Comment: @tripleee Change the source string can be done only by developers, as well as adding a new context to translatable string. The latter method is preferred as I described above, hence no reason to use another word (sender instead from) as source string.